# Magento 2 : Disabled product is removed from the cart

Tags: checkout, addtocart, shopping-cart, cart-items

I want to set a message when a disabled product is removed from the cart. Does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index">
        <observer name="vendor_module_quote_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\BeforeQuote" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Also create Observer

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class BeforeQuote implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $notAdded = [];
        $deleted = [];
        foreach ($quote->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code you get disabled items only one time.